# Can't connect to camera on Genymotion

Tags: android, android-camera, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion v2.2.2 and Samsung Galaxy S4 -4.4.2 or Motorola MotoX image and Windows 7 x64.
I enabled the camera with the Camera widget. I can see the picture of the camera in preview, but when I try to take a picture from any of the applications even the already installed Camera app it says cannot connect to the camera. It works ok under Android v4.1.1.
Has anyone experienced similar?

Comment: It works on Android v4.3 too.

Answer (score 4):

[EDITED]
it happen to me too, so i took a experiment to the way to activate the camera and came to this conclusion :

1. Restart Ur GENYMOTION
2. Start the virtual device that 4.1 below (cause this VD should open the camera app)
3. open the camera apps (without active the VD camera option(Ctrl +3) )
4. Press Ctrl+3 to open VD Camera Option and turn the camera then change either front or back camera to webcam (now u should see the result in camera apps )
5. then close the VD and start any VD above 4.1
6. when active the camera DON'T CHANGE THE PREVIEW FROM NONE TO OTHER (such as front or back)
7. DON'T CHANGE THE OPTION DUMMYWEBCAM TO WEBCAM OR OTHER To because it will make the camera is assumpted taken by the other application and can't be use by the genymotion other Apps
8. Open The Camera Apps and let it until it show running geny logo
9. Click CTRL+ 3 then change the option DUMMYWEBCAM to Other that what u desire

and by the way i just took experiment after update the Genymotion to the latest one, i use version 2.3.0

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it did not work for me, sorry. Although with another trick I was able to make it work once again. Unfortunately I could not elaborate it more thoroughly because I changed to Windows 8, so I cannot describe the steps here. Now the whole Genymotion does not work for me at all.

Comment: can u explain what the error message that appear ? , usually genymotion generate error message

Comment: Just like to say thanks ibrahim for your solution, I just found your answer today and even with Genymotion 2.8.1 this solution works great.